# VHDL Integer Range Output Bus Width

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm currently working on writing a simple counter in VHDL, trying to genericize it as much as possible. Ideally I end up with a counter that can pause, count up/down, and take just two integer (min, max) values to determine the appropriate bus widths.

As far as I can tell, in order to get an integer of a given range, I just need to delcare

`VARIABLE cnt: INTEGER RANGE min TO max := 0`

Where min and max are defined as generics (both integers) in the entity. My understanding of this is that if min is 0, max is 5, for example, it will create an integer variable of 3 bits.

My problem is that I actually want to *output* this integer. So, naturally, I write

`counterOut : OUT INTEGER RANGE min TO max`

But this does not appear to be doing what I need. I'm generating a schematic block in Quartus Prime from this, and it creates a *bus output* from [min...max]. For example, if min = 0, max = 65, it outputs a 66 bit bus. Instead of the seven bit bus it should.

If I restricted the counter to unsigned values I might be able to just math out the output bus size, but I'd like to keep this as flexible as possible, and of course I'd like to know what I'm actually doing wrong and how to do it properly.

TL;DR: I want a VHDL entity to take generic min,max values, and generate an integer output bus of the required width to hold the range of values. How do?

If it matters, I'm using Quartus Prime Lite Edition V20.1.0 at the moment.

Note: I know I can use STD_LOGIC_VECTOR instead, but it is going to simulate significantly slower and is less easy to use than the integer type as far as I have read. I can provide more of my code if necessary, but it's really this one line that's the problem as far as I can tell.

EDIT: It's got to be an issue with the generics, since hardcoding in values gives expected behavior. Here's my generic block in case I've done anything wrong there,

```
    GENERIC (modulo : INTEGER := 32;
                min : INTEGER := 0;
                max : INTEGER := 64);
```

EDIT 2:

Complete implementation is shown below

````
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY Counter IS
    GENERIC (modulo : INTEGER := 32;
                min : INTEGER := 0;
                max : INTEGER := 64);
    PORT( pause : IN STD_LOGIC;
            direction : IN STD_LOGIC; -- 1 is up, 0 is down
            clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
            counterOut : OUT INTEGER RANGE min TO max --RANGE 0 TO 32 -- THIS line is the one generating an incorrect output bus width
            );
END ENTITY Counter; 
-- or entity

ARCHITECTURE CounterArch OF Counter IS
BEGIN
    PROCESS(direction, pause, clk)
    VARIABLE cnt : INTEGER RANGE min TO max := 0; 
    VARIABLE dir : INTEGER;
    BEGIN
    IF direction = '1' THEN
        dir := 1;
    ELSE
        dir := -1;
    END IF;
    IF clk'EVENT AND clk = '1' THEN
        IF pause = '0'THEN
            IF (cnt = modulo AND direction = '1') THEN
                cnt := min; -- If we're counting up and hit modulo, reset to min value.
            ELSIF (cnt = min AND direction = '0') THEN
                cnt := modulo; --Counting down hit 0, go back to modulo.
            ELSE
                cnt := cnt + dir;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    counterOut <= cnt;
    END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE CounterArch;
```
````

Comment: Why do you use `integer` instead of `signed/unsigned`?

Comment: @po.pe Well, integer over unsigned because I'd like this to be as generic as possible, I might need a signed counter one day (not sure why, but you know). As far as not using unsigned, I don't think my professor ever mentioned the signed/unsigned data types at all thus far. I've seen them, but not used them. I do believe that math should be easier working with integers than the unsigned type, although I may be wrong.
EDIT: Enter finishes the comment whoops.
I'm not opposed to switching data types if it's a better idea, but I'd also just like to know why I'm getting the weird behavior I am.

Comment: Can you show us your complete implementation?

Comment: @po.pe Gladly, just added it to the main post as an edit. Thanks for taking a look at it!

Comment: What are you doing with this signal outside the entity? Seems like it's not strictly regulated how integer ports have to be infered by the synthesizer.

Comment: I'm currently using Quartus Prime to generate a symbol file then using the schematic editor to chain a few counters for clocking and counting. It's when I generate the symbol that it gives me the wrong bus size output.
I think you're right that it's not inferring the ports how I expect, I think Quartus is making a different assumption on how to synthesize it when using generics.
Ideally I'd like to have (min,max) in integers for ease of use, but it's looking like it'll probably be easiest to just define width as a generic and convert the output to an unsigned or std_logic_vector. Thanks!

Comment: I'd anyway not use integers in port entities if possible.